# Can't get value from an array (c)

Tags: c, arrays

I'm reading a code from a ppm file and store the value of each pixel in p1, array of pixel, which is a struct of .red .green .blue (int). I managed to create a "Negative Filter" of the picture, however. I'm trying to get a black and white by taking the mean of red, green, and blue pixel. 
I have pixel p1, pixel p2(negative filter) and int p3(b&w). However every action that have p3 = ...., will stop responding. such as

```
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
                p3[i][j] = ((p1[i][j].red + p1[i][j].green + p1[i][j].blue)/3);
            }
    }
```

or

```
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
            fprintf(pf3, "%d", p3[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

However when I change int p3[WIDTH][HEIGHT] to char p3[WIDTH][HEIGHT], the program runs but gives a wrong output. Both int and char, compiled successfully. Can someone help me? thanks.

EDIT:
What I'm hoping is I could create a .pgm black and white extension of picture from .ppm by inputting .ppm value to pixel p1[WIDTH][HEIGHT] in .red, .green, and .blue. Then calculate the mean of RGB and assign it in int p3 before being written in .pgm.

What I got when using int p3, it crashes when I run the .exe stopped working without giving any error.

When I use char p3, it run perfectly, but it gives all negative value for the mean of all the pixel. (This already being helped by putting unsigned infront of the char thanks to @egoteclair)

My new question would be why can't I use int instead of unsigned char?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry, I'm pretty new here. thank you for your reminder I will edit the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal char size is 8-bit. The first bit will be used for the sign extension. In a 24 bit png file each color-field contains 8 bits.

```
24 / 3 = 8
```

So try to use unsigned char instead of char. This allows you to use the complete 8 bits of the char.

Comment: It worked! but can you explain me why does integer doesn't work? Thank you before